# Scrape ASP.NET Website with heavy javascript calls

Tags: asp.net

I want to scrape this website - https://recorder.co.clark.nv.us/RecorderEcommerce/default.aspx.

I need to simulate clicking the 'Parcel #' link first then entering a value (i.e. 1234) into the Parcel # textbox and clicking search.

I need to scrape the data in the table which is shown at the bottom.

I'd like to write this in ASP.NET so I can push the Parcel # etc parameters through as part of the request. Once I get that request back, I'm confident I can parse it myself, I'm just not sure how I should exactly send the original request as it's not as simple as sending across parameters?

Answer (score 0):

In your question you've specified both Javascript and asp.net so I really have no idea what technologies you're planning on using. I'd recommend [HtmlAgility pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It has a download from url option. It'll help with the parsing too.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.Load("https://recorder.co.clark.nv.us/RecorderEcommerce/default.aspx");
```

Comment: Sorry, I updated the title. The target website has a lot of javascript / resubmits which is making it confusing for me to identify the exact GET / POST request I need to make.
Essentially, I don't want to have to 'simulate' clicking of buttons etc, I'd rather send the actual GET/POST request generated as per my scenario above.

I would like to implement this using ASP.NET.

Part of the problem I see with the agility pack and the solution you've outlined below is, how would I simulate those clicks etc I've outlined?

Comment: If it's that complex you're better using something like Fiddler to capture the requests and using a WebRequest object to mimic them... I'm assuming you can't just do a File->Save in your browser?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot just do File > Save in the browser - I need to automate it as I have a number of queries I'll be running a day